# h2 database java heap issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, heap-memory, h2

Our application loads data from an avro file into in memory h2 database using java spring boot. I have a 145000000 rows to insert and I'm getting java heap error. it works fine with 2 million rows. How can I fix this issue?

Error pasted below
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Out of memory.; SQL statement:
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:617) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:341) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:233) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:488) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Can you insert rows in batch? 10000 by 10000 for example?

Comment: Which are your memory settings ? Increased them already ?

Comment: If it works with 2 million rows, that doesn't mean it will work with 145 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load 145M rows into memory.  So you obviously need to give the JVM more memory to handle that amount of storage.

Look into adding/changing your `-Xmx` JVM parameter to allocate more memory.  See here for more info:

[What are the -Xms and -Xmx parameters when starting JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvm)

Comment: I increased jvm memory and it worked

Comment: @Jewels: if possible, can you please post sample code? I am struggling with same issue with 30M records.